# Width JTable Cell fit to Width Value

Tags: java, swing, jtable

1.how to set Width JTable Cell fit to Width Value?

2.how to create JTable beauty?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) You need set width to TableColumn e.g.

```
TableColumn col = table.getColumnModel().getColumn(vColIndex);
int width = 100;
col.setPreferredWidth(width);
```

2) You need to specifies Renderers for cells, table ...

Comment: So this works... sometimes.  But there are LOTS of idiosyncrasies of the actual column width that is used.  Here are a few things to consider: col.setMaxWidth(...); table.setAutoResizeMode(JTable.AUTO_RESIZE_OFF); and last, if you call table.setModel, the table columns will be reset, so another call to table.getColumnModel().getColumn(...).setPreferredWidth(...) will be necessary.

Answer (score 1):

1) You can use following method to calculate an expected column cell width ragarding its content

```
FontMetrics metrics = table.getFontMetrics(table.getFont());
int width = metrics.stringWidth(strCellContent);
```

Comment: no, that doesn't help: you can't know what/how the rendering component is decides to show the cell content